# What happen to the "tail" of a generator and its returned value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator

Consider the following definition for a Python generator:

```py
def gen(x):

    print("-- BEGIN --")
    y = x + 1
    yield y

    #-- 'tail' of the generator
    z = y + 1
    print("z = %d" % z)
    print("-- END --")

    return z
```

(I) If one uses this generator as in

```py
g1 = gen(1)
print( next(g1) )
```

the output will be

```
-- BEGIN --
2
```

Another `next(g1)` will produce

```
z = 3
-- END --
```

along with a `StopIteration` exception.

(II) If one exhausts the `g1` generator, e.g., via `list`

```py
g1 = gen(1)
print("result =", list(g1) )
```

the output will be

```
-- BEGIN --
z = 3
-- END --
result = [2]
```

without any exception.

### Questions:

- What happens to the "tail" of the generator in case (I)? When will it be executed, if ever?
- Why did the tail did not execute in case (I), but executed in case (II)?
- Is there a standard way to exhaust the generator in a *single* step, like what `list` operation does in `list(g1)`?
- Is it possible to recover the final returned value, `z`, after exhaustion?

Comment: Possible duplicate?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16780002/return-in-generator-together-with-yield-in-python-3-3

Comment: So, what are you actually trying to accomplish here, why are you mixing `yield` and `return`? A generator is simple. It starts executing the first time you call `next`, until it reaches a yield. It keeps doing this until there are no yields, or forever potentially. If the function ends without another yield, it simply raises `StopIteration`, but it will still execute until it is finished. `return` in a generator does something special, see the link I posted above

Comment: "Is there a standard way to exhaust the generator in a single step" iterate over it? What is a "single step"? You could call *list*, or whatever. You could also define your own heleper function: `def consume(g): for x in g: pass` which won't populate a data-structure, if that is what you are trying to avoid...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14183803/what-is-the-difference-between-raise-stopiteration-and-a-return-statement-in-gen/30217723 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34073370/best-way-to-receive-the-return-value-from-a-python-generator

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga : I am not trying to achieve something particular here; just to understand how generators work.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga : so the "tail" will be executed when one performs a `next` after the last `yield`, and then `return` raises `StopIteration` exception?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga : By a "single-step exhaustion", I meant something _built-in_ like `z = exhaust(g1)`, instead of `list(g1)`, which would receive also the final returned value.

Comment: @AlQuemist essentially, for more details, check out that other question I linked to. There is no `exhaust` built-in, but you could try to `consume` recipe in the [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) documentation.

Comment: But as for the `return` value, in a generator, `return x` will be equivalent to `raise StopIteration(x)`, so to retrieve the value  `catch StopIteration as e` and the `x` will be in `e.value`. I don't think that was a use-case in mind, though.