# How to pass information together with the end of a generator in Python? Raising a StopIteration(myobj) is not being caught

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, iterator, generator

I have found an elegant solution for the problem of returning a final information after generator exhaustion, which is to put the desired content inside StopIteration. This require manually raising the Exception at the end of the generator function. 
**However, it seems not possible to caught from the outside.** The only way it worked was with a custom exception, which breaks the generator protocol for anyone not interested in the returned value (in a `for` statement for instance).

```
def generator():
    for i in range(3):
        print('inside', i)
        yield i
    print('raising...')
    raise StopIteration('<<Some accumulated result.>>')

p = generator()
try:
    while True:
        print('\n Trying...')
        print('outside', next(p))
except StopIteration as e:
    print('handling', e.arg
```

Output:

```
Trying...
inside 0
outside 0

Trying...
inside 1
outside 1

Trying...
inside 2
outside 2

Trying...
raising...
RuntimeError: generator raised StopIteration
```

Expected output:

```
Trying...
inside 0
outside 0

Trying...
inside 1
outside 1

Trying...
inside 2
outside 2

Trying...
raising...
handling ('<<Some accumulated result.>>')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the generator return value [seems to be put inside the exception by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34073370/best-way-to-receive-the-return-value-from-a-python-generator):

```
def generator():
    for i in range(3):
        print('inside', i)
        yield i
    print('raising...')
    return '<<Some accumulated result.>>'


p = generator()
try:
    while True:
        print('\n Trying...')
        print('outside', next(p))
except StopIteration as e:
    print('handling', e.args)
```

Output:

```
Trying...
inside 0
outside 0

Trying...
inside 1
outside 1

Trying...
inside 2
outside 2

Trying...
raising...
handling ('<<Some accumulated result.>>')
```