# Get a return value from a decorator with generator in python

Tags: python, generator, decorator, return-value

I have a generator in Python. Let's say:

```
def gen(*args, **kwargs):
    yield 1
    yield 2
    return 3
```

Now, I want following. I create a generator object `gen_obj = gen()`
Then I do something with it, typically `value = next(gen)`
and at the end I want to do something like this:
`returned_value = gen.value # it should return 3`

Some [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34073370/best-way-to-receive-the-return-value-from-a-python-generator) to overcome this particular issue exist, but I will make it more complicated.
In fact, I do not have a simple generator, but I have a decorator:

```
def MakeGeneratorFromFcn(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs):
        if isgeneratorfunction(func):
            gen = func(*args, **kwargs)  # if it is generator, then embed yielding
            retval = yield from gen
            return retval
        return func(*args, **kwargs) # otherwise this wrapped_func is already a generator, return the api_func

    return wrapped_func
```

So at the end I would like to do something like this:

```
@MakeGeneratorFromFcn
def foo():
    return 10

gen = foo()
for i in gen:
    print(i)
gen.value  # return 10; this is missing
```

and also this would be working:

```
@MakeGeneratorFromFcn
def foo():
    yield 1
    return 10

gen = foo()
for i in gen:
    print(i)
gen.value  # return 10; this is missing
```

**EDIT #1:**
To solve that, I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34073775/1104897) and with modification:

```
class ValueKeepingGenerator(object):
    def __init__(self, g):
        self.g = g
        self.value = None
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    def __next__(self):
        self.value = next(self.g)
        return self.value
```

Together with another decoration "from fcn to generator" I was able to make the code running for my purposes.

Comment: Can w ask *why* you want to do this, with a real-world example of what you want to achieve. This is a relatively esoteric use case which iisn't how generators are designed to be used, so any solution will likely be a bit of a 'hack', so rreviewing the motivation is important!

Comment: If you want ``gen.value`` to be the ``result``... why don't you assign ``result`` to ``gen.value``? Just ``wrapped_func.value = result`` should do. How does the case of a decorator invalidate the answers that do exactly that, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34073559/5349916)?

Comment: @match the use case is in a framework I am developing. The framework schedules different tasks or functions (when used with the decoration) and runs it. I would like to get a return value after the generator / function is finished.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi it is because you cannot create an attribute to a generator object. I.e. `gen = generator(); for i in gen: print(i); gen.value = 10` - the last assignment won't work

Comment: Make it a class as in the mentioned answer, then? [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34073775/5349916) even shows how to apply such a class via decorator.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I found the root cause. The example in the answer is not working with next(), I had to add iteration implementation to the class. I will update...