# A better way to grab the return of a generator?

Tags: python, generator

First of all, this question is different from ["Best way to receive the 'return' value from a python generator" question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34073370/best-way-to-receive-the-return-value-from-a-python-generator), because that question has a generator that does not receive values from `yield`.

This question concerns a generator that actually receives values via the `yield` mechanism.

---

So I have a code that looks kind of like this:

```py
def gen():
    ...
    # accumulator is defined here
    ...
    while (incoming := (yield)) is not None:
        ...
        # Do things with incoming
        # And put in accumulator
        accumulator.consume(processed_incoming)
        ...
    return accumulator
```

Later on it gets invoked like so:

```py
    ...
    g = gen()
    for item in dataset:
        g.send(item)
    # Exhausted the dataset, let's grab the accumulator
    try:
        g.send(None)
    except StopIteration as si:
        result = si.value
    # continue our merry way
    ...
```

Is there a better way to grab the return value of `gen()` besides catching the `StopIteration` exception?

Comment: The generator doesn't seem to generate anything, so maybe the better solution would be to not use a generator?

Comment: A context manager would probably be better. Its `__enter__` method can return the thing that will accumulate stuff, then you can access the accumulator from the `__exit__` method or the thing returned by `__enter__` (or any time after the `__exit__` method is called).

Comment: Perhaps you should have a class that contains the generator function as a member.  Then you could just call a different function on that object.