# What is the difference between exhausting a generator using "for i in generator" and next(generator)

Tags: python, generator

I want to learn how to use the return value of a generator (but this not what I'm concerned with now).

After searching, they said that I can get the return value from `StopIteration` when the generator is exhausted, so I tested it with the following code:

```
def my_generator():
    yield 1
    yield 2
    yield 3
    return "done"


def exhaust_generator(_gen):
    print("===============================================\n")
    print("exhaust_generator")
    try:
        while True:
            print(next(_gen))
    except StopIteration as e:
        print(f"Return value: '{e.value}'")


def exhaust_generator_iter(_gen):
    print("===============================================\n")
    print("exhaust_generator_iter")
    try:
        for i in _gen:
            print(i)
        print(next(_gen))
    except StopIteration as e:
        print(f"Return value: {e.value}")


gen = my_generator()
gen2 = my_generator()
exhaust_generator(gen)
exhaust_generator_iter(gen2)
```

```
===============================================

exhaust_generator
1
2
3
Return value: 'done'
===============================================

exhaust_generator_iter
1
2
3
Return value: None
```

As you can see, the return value is different between the two versions of exhausting the generator and I wonder why.

Searched google but it has not been helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your first example with the `while`, you're catching the first `StopIteration` exception raised by the generator when it's initially exhausted.

In your second example with the `for`, you're catching a *subsequent* `StopIteration` exception raised by calling `next()` a second time *after* the generator has already been exhausted (by the `for`, which caught that initial exception).

Comment: (As far as I know, there is no way to get that `"done"` return value via a `for`, since the exception gets eaten, but maybe somebody knows an arcane trick that I don't?)

Comment: Oh, I was too slow :)

Comment: [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41875793/14015737) shows a way to get the return value by using a helper function with the `for` loop.

Comment: "yo, I heard you like generators, so I put your generator in a generator!"  That does seem like the most graceful way to do it though.

Comment: Seems like there's probably a PEP in there somewhere, maybe something like `for ... else as gen_ret:` to be able to capture the generator return at the end of the loop if it's exhausted.

Comment: Thank you, I forgot that 'StopIteration' being used to exit the loop

Comment: This PEP answers many of my questions about generator but it still like a magic to me. :P
https://peps.python.org/pep-0380/

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand, the `for` loop internally also calls `next()` and eventually catches the `StopIteration`, so it knows when to stop calling `next()`.

Your `next()` call in `exhaust_generator_iter` then raises *a second* `StopIteration` but without the passed value.

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34073370/14015737) and its answers explore ways to receive the `return` value from a generator, i.a. using a utility class or dependency injection.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. From what I've searched yesterday it looks like it calls `iter()` to get Iterable (that usually itself) and call `next()` on that Iterable. That make me think that `iter()` is causing the difference I've asked about